# Why can't I just link to site.url?

Tags: html, gitlab, jekyll

I have a site that built with Jekyll. I just want my name on the top left corner, part of my header, to link to my home page. It should just link to vivian-duong.gitlab.io. However, when I click on it, I get sent to vivian-duong.gitlab.io/vivian-duong.gitlab.io. And when I click my name again, I get vivian-duong.gitlab.io/vivian-duong.gitlab.io/vivian-duong.gitlab.io which is broken. That page does not exist.

How do I make it so my name is just a link to my home page?

[image: homepage]

In my _config.yml file, url is let to vivian-duong.gitlab.io

```
permalink: /:categories/:title.html
url: "vivian-duong.gitlab.io"

--other stuff--
```

In my header.html

```
<div id='logo'><a href={{site.url}}>{{site.first_name}}</a> <a href={{site.url}} id='logo_docs'>
{{site.last_name}}</a> (Site Under Construction)</div>
```

Near the top of all my .html files

```
        <div id='layout'>
            {% include header.html %}
            <div style='clear: both'></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a prepend to your url:

```
url: "https://vivian-duong.gitlab.io"
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked!
That makes it an absolute url. vivian-duong.gitlab.io is just a relative url.